# Right value for eCPM in AdMob Mediation

Tags: android, admob

In AdMob mediation there is an option to set the eCPM value for different networks. How do I decide the best eCPM value for a network and alter that using the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Admob mediation the eCPM values that you define for each network are currently used just to determine the order in which networks are polled for an ad impression.

If you define values about what you seem to be receiving from each network then it will provide a good ordering. If in doubt just guess and then refine later.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I needed to realize is that mediation is meaningless unless you're serving ads from multiple networks. Admob uses the mediation dollar amount when deciding which network's ads it will attempt to serve first while filling your requests, highest to lowest. By analyzing historical data, you should set the network's eCPM based on the amount of revenue you'd expect to receive per 1000 impressions displayed in your app.

I have no idea how to alter the value using code, but I don't understand how that would benefit you either.